# Duplicates in a dictionary python

Tags: python

It is possible to have duplicates in a list?

eg:

```
joe
3
callan
4
callan
3
```

Would I be able to put this information into a dictionary without overriding the key?

Comment: be a lit more clear and yes it possible to have duplicate in list but not in dictonary key's

Answer (score 4):

Dictionary keys are unique, but you can use lists as values:

```
mydict = {"joe": [3], "callan": [3,4]}
```

To add/append an item to a dictionary, use `setdefault`:

```
In [2]: mydict.setdefault("will", []).append(2)
In [3]: mydict.setdefault("joe", []).append(5)

In [4]: mydict
Out[4]: {'callan': [3, 4], 'joe': [3, 5], 'will': [2]}
```

Or use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
In [12]: mydict = defaultdict(list)
In [13]: mydict.update({"joe": [3], "callan": [3,4]})

In [14]: mydict
Out[14]: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'joe': [3], 'callan': [3, 4]})

In [15]: mydict["will"].append(2)
In [16]: mydict["joe"].append(5)
In [17]: mydict
Out[17]: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'joe': [3, 5], 'will': [2], 'callan': [3,4]})
```